# Example of a tensor triangulated category with two different monoidal t-structures?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, triangulated-categories

1. What's an example of a tensor triangulated category / symmetric monoidal stable $\infty$-category with two different monoidal $t$-structures?
2. While I'm at it: is there an example of a tensor triangulated category which doesn't admit any monoidal $t$-structure?

For reference (I'm not sure whether the definitions used vary in practice), I'm thinking in terms of stable $\infty$-categories, and to say that a $t$-structure is monoidal just means that the inclusion $\mathcal C_{\geq 0} \to \mathcal C$ is a strong symmetric monoidal functor, i.e. the monoidal unit is in $\mathcal C_{\geq 0}$ and $\mathcal C_{\geq 0}$ is closed under $\otimes$.

I'm starting to get the sense that the roles played by the monoidal structure and the $t$-structure are somewhat redundant; I'm not sure if I should trust this sense.

Comment: For 1) what if you shift the usual $t$ structure on ${\rm Mod}~ R$  one step to the right?

Comment: I'd say that it is natural to consider "equivalent" t-structures that are in the same $\Sigma$-orbit. My 2 cents on 1: in good cases tensor structures on derived $\infty$-categories of rings are inherited by monoidal structures on categories of chain complexes, regarded as self-enriched and then simplicial via Dold-Kan in the standard way done in HA1. Now, is there a module category with two inherently different monoidal structures? (cntnd)

Comment: (cntnd) I'd also suggest to look at t-structures on spectra: there is plenty of t-structures $t_E$ whose classes are $\{X \in \text{Sp} \mid X\land E = 0\}$ and the orthogonal thereof. These are monoidal, right?

Comment: For 1) you can consider derived category of ${\mathbb Z}-$graded vector spaces. It has an obvious $t-$structure, but also less obvious one with the heart spanned by $V_i[i]$ (space of grading $i$ in homological degree $-i$).

Comment: Stable categories of modular representations of finite groups are likely to give examples for 2.

Comment: @PhilTosteson I get confused by left and right, but if $(\mathcal C, \mathcal C_{\geq 0})$ is a monoidal $t$-structure with unit $I$, then $I \in \mathcal C_{\geq 0} \setminus \mathcal C_{\geq 1}$. For if $I \in \mathcal C_{\geq 1}$, then for any $X \in \mathcal C_{\geq n}$ we have $X = I \otimes X \in \mathcal C_{\geq n+1}$, so that $\mathcal C_{\geq n} = \mathcal C_{\geq m}$ for all $m,n$. Thus if a shift of a monoidal $t$-structure is monoidal, then the shift coincides with the original $t$-structure.

Comment: @Fosco Thanks! These $t$-structures do appear to be monoidal and moreover are very strange to me since $\mathcal C_{\geq m} = \mathcal C_{\geq n}$ for all $m,n$ and is a stable category! And similarly for bounding above. This wasn't even on my radar in thinking about $t$-structures. I suppose it means these $t$-structures are very far from being either left or right complete...

Comment: @VictorOstrik Thanks! But are these $t$-structures on the derived category of graded vector spaces really both monoidal with respect to the same monoidal structure? It seems to me I need to shift the usual monoidal structure to get the second one to be a monoidal $t$-structure...

Comment: @TimCampion: I believe that no change of tensor structure is needed. Here is explicit description of this $t-$structure: ${\mathcal C}_{\ge 0}$ consists of objects with $i-$th cohomology concentrated in degrees $\le i$; ${\mathcal C}_{\le 0}$ consists of objects with $H^i$ concentrated in degrees $\ge i$.

Comment: I might be wrong, but if you tilt the standard t-structure of $D^{b}(P^{1})$ by the cotilting torsion pair $(\{ \mathcal{O}(n), n\geq 0, \mathcal{O}_{x}, x\in P^{1}\}, \{ \mathcal{O}(n), n<0\})$ then the resulting t-structure is compatible with the usual monoidal structure on $D^{b}(P^1)$ , no? The t-structure is described properly in page 25 of math/0312442

Comment: Is there a reference for monoidal $t$-structures? The only article I could find that summarizes the basics is in the M.Bondarko and F.Deglise paper.